# Install magento theme manually from .zip

Tags: magento, themes, magento-1.8

I have been trying to install a theme which has the following folder structure to magento community installation but I never get it to work:

```
theme
├── app
│   ├── code
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── design
│   │   ├── adminhtml
│   │   │   └── default
│   │   └── frontend
│   │       ├── base
│   │       ├── default
│   │       └── flatshop
│   ├── etc
│   │   └── modules
│   │       └── ...
│   └── locale
│       └── ...
├── js
│   ├── ...
├── lib
│   └── ...
├── media
│   └── ...
└── skin
    ├── adminhtml
    │   └── default
    │       └── flatshop
    └── frontend
        ├── base
        │   └── default
        ├── default
        │   └── default
        └── flatshop
            └── default
```

*What* should I copy to *where* in my magento installation? It’s for magento community 1.8.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "theme" actually looks like it's a theme **and** a module.  (I'm assuming the `...` is a stand in for a huge list of files.

Your theme's folder structure mirrors a Magento folder structure.  If you look at your Magento system you'll see it has a

```
app/code/...
app/design/frontend
```

While the author of the theme is the only one who can tell you how to install it, it's a good bet you'll just want to copy the files from your archive into the same folder locations in your Magento system.  The OS X `ditto` command does this well.

Comment: That was it. Although it worked when copying it to the server itself. For some reason, when using MAMP (OS X 10.9.2) it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

goto System =>Configuration=>Design settings

add **flatshop** instead of default on package name area.

Comment: I have the .zip uncompressed in another directory. what files from this uncompressed folder should I copy to the magento folder?

Comment: normally theme provider give guide on that. you need to copy several folders depending on the theme. try this http://blog.nexcess.net/2011/06/10/how-to-manually-install-a-magento-theme/